# TimeStamps in Mongoid Embedded Documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am having a collection A which embeds collection B. Collection A as well as collection B includes Mongoid Timestamps (created_at and updated_at).

Now when I create a new entry of collection B (embedded object) using Rails admin, time stamps saved in Database are nil. But if I create a entry from rails console or from a normal api, then timestamps saved in database are not nil.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
class B
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  field :user_id,    type: String
  field :message,    type: String
  field :status,     type: Integer, default: 1
  field :spam_count, type: Integer, default: 0

  embedded_in :A
```

Class B is embedded in class A. When a entry of B is created inside A through rails admin, then created_at and updated_at fields of B are getting saved as nil.

Comment: Can you post what code you've written so far?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without `class A` or information what mongoid version you use (I'll assume 5.x) I have do some wild guess here that you are missing the cascade_callbacks flag on your embedded relation.

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :albums, cascade_callbacks: true
end
```